# SQL Server 2016. Clone/Copy DB on same server to Existing different DB keep same files

Tags: sql, sql-server

I did my homework on how to copy a database, some say need new name for mdf and log files, some say that REPLACE will take care of it.

I'm on same server, SQL Server 2016. I don't have freedom to create new files or do any copy or renames of them. Can not use DBCC as well (for CLONE).

```
SourceDB is existing db : 10 tables.
SourceDB_Data  c:\SPath\SourceDB.mdf
SourceDB Log  c:\SPath\SourceDB_log.ldf

NewDB is existing db : 3 tables, 2 views
NewDB_Data c:\NewDBPath\NewDB.mdf
NewDB_Log  c:\NewDBPath\NewDB_log.ldf
```

Main thing that structure of those databases are totally different, but I need to copy structure and all content into NewDB. I can NOT drop/ recreate it, too many handles connected to NewDB and they will start ringing if it will disappear. Alas this rules I have.  I can NOT drop this NewDB in any case.

Though. I can do DDL on NewDB, maybe as last resort I can recreate SourceDB Schema on it?

My plan still go with bkup just for the case. Will this work and keep same logical and physical files names on NewDB?  Don't want to produce any error). Thanks

1. Bkup SourceDB
   'c:\Path\to\SourceDB.buk'
2. Set NewDB into single mode
3. Run script:

   Restore Database  NewDB From Disk = 'c:\Path\to\SourceDB.bak' **With Replace**

Goal to get NewDB (keep old name) with NewDB.MDF names and and content of SourceDB.

Comment: What purpose would backing up and restoring a database over itself serve, other than to put the database back to the position it was at the point of the back up? Clone means you want 2 copies, not the replace the existing one.

Comment: 2 databases can't use the same files either. If you want 2 databases, they need to have separate files.

Comment: You'll also need `with move` to restore the logical files of SourceDB on top of the physical files of NewDB, and of course they have to have the same number of database and log files.

Comment: Thanks all, and DB ! I have a perfect sense to clone db, I just need clone context of it.